# Open Active Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have VBA code that should pick up the active workbook (and use the data to open a Word Document and leave the mail merged document open ready for review/saving).

It worked once but now it isn't picking up the open spreadsheet. It opens a 'Select Table' window of which the only option is the XLSTART.xls spreadsheet with no data.

How do I pick up the active workbook?

```
Sub Mailmerge()
    Dim wd As Object
    Dim wdocSource As Object
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     ' Word constants
    Const wdFormLetters = 0, wdOpenFormatAuto = 0
    Const wdSendToNewDocument = 0, wdDefaultFirstRecord = 1, wdDefaultLastRecord = -16
    Dim strWorkbookName As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If wd Is Nothing Then
        Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set wdocSource = wd.Documents.Open("File Name for Mail Merge doc, this bit works when not redacted!")
    strWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name
    wdocSource.Mailmerge.MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
    wdocSource.Mailmerge.OpenDataSource _
      Name:=strWorkbookName, _
      AddToRecentFiles:=True, _
      Revert:=False, _
      Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
      Connection:="Data Source=" & strWorkbookName & ";Mode=Read", _
      SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Sheet2$`"
    With wdocSource.Mailmerge
        .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
        .SuppressBlankLines = True
        With .DataSource
            .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord
            .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord
        End With
        .Execute Pause:=False
    End With
    wd.Visible = True
    wdocSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Set wdocSource = Nothing
    Set wd = Nothing
End Sub
```